# Authorize Middleware not block the request

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

To validate my API access for the selected users i had write the Middleware for the validate user http request 
Middleware is executing and alter the StatusCode of request

but still API method is executing

here is my middleware

```
 httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
 httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid username or password.");

return _next(httpContext);
```

here im register the Middleware

```
app.UseAuthenticationMiddleware();
```

here is my API method

```
[HttpPost]       
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePolicy([FromBody] Customer customerDetails)
```

here i also add the [Authorize] add its not working return the 500 error

any suggestions ?

Comment: That's because you call `await _next(httpContext)`. This executes the **next** middleware in the pipeline. Remove it (conditionally) and it won't called the middlewares further in the pipeline

Comment: @Tseng my method should have return type, because if its success i need to move next middleware 
public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

Comment: oh we can use async and await  lets try

Comment: its working thank you friend make your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing a custom middleware, you have to call `await _next(httpContext)` to execute the next middleware in the pipeline.

Remove it (conditionally) and it won't called the middlewares further in the pipeline.

```
if(someConditionIsTrue)
{
    await _next(httpContext);
}
```

Alternatively you can just return a completed task via `return Task.Completed;` instead of `return _next(httpContext)`, if don't want to call other middlewares in the pipeline.

But its a micro optimization, since the 2nd one doesn't invoke an async state machine.